# mutate new column based on sequence of time stamp in dbplyr

Tags: mysql, r, postgresql, dplyr, dbplyr

I have a dataset from a `PostgreSQL` DB, which I have two columns:

---

`id` = the ID of a participant

`time_stamp` = the time stamp of the recorded measurement

---

I need to work with `dbplyr` in order to mutate a new column based on the sequence of `time_stamp`. In other words, if the `time_stamp` is in sequence (meaning that it is in **one minute** intervals), this is recognized as **one event**.

For example, this is my dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(lubridate)

mf <- memdb_frame(
  id = "id001", 
  time_stamp = c(
    seq(from = as_datetime("2021-01-01 08:00:00"), to = as_datetime("2021-01-01 08:03:00"), by = "1 min"),
    seq(from = as_datetime("2021-01-01 08:05:00"), to = as_datetime("2021-01-01 08:08:00"), by = "1 min"),
    seq(from = as_datetime("2021-01-01 08:12:00"), to = as_datetime("2021-01-01 08:18:00"), by = "1 min")
  )
)

mf %>% 
  collect() %>% 
  mutate(time_stamp = as_datetime(time_stamp))

#> # A tibble: 15 x 2
#>    id    time_stamp         
#>    <chr> <dttm>             
#>  1 id001 2021-01-01 08:00:00
#>  2 id001 2021-01-01 08:01:00
#>  3 id001 2021-01-01 08:02:00
#>  4 id001 2021-01-01 08:03:00
#>  5 id001 2021-01-01 08:05:00
#>  6 id001 2021-01-01 08:06:00
#>  7 id001 2021-01-01 08:07:00
#>  8 id001 2021-01-01 08:08:00
#>  9 id001 2021-01-01 08:12:00
#> 10 id001 2021-01-01 08:13:00
#> 11 id001 2021-01-01 08:14:00
#> 12 id001 2021-01-01 08:15:00
#> 13 id001 2021-01-01 08:16:00
#> 14 id001 2021-01-01 08:17:00
#> 15 id001 2021-01-01 08:18:00
```

Now, I need to recognize the **events**. That means, find `time_stamps` that happened in **sequence** (sequence = 1 minute interval). As an example, this would be my **expected output**:

```r
#> # A tibble: 15 x 3
#>    id    time_stamp          events 
#>    <chr> <dttm>              <chr>  
#>  1 id001 2021-01-01 08:00:00 event_1
#>  2 id001 2021-01-01 08:01:00 event_1
#>  3 id001 2021-01-01 08:02:00 event_1
#>  4 id001 2021-01-01 08:03:00 event_1
#>  5 id001 2021-01-01 08:05:00 event_2
#>  6 id001 2021-01-01 08:06:00 event_2
#>  7 id001 2021-01-01 08:07:00 event_2
#>  8 id001 2021-01-01 08:08:00 event_2
#>  9 id001 2021-01-01 08:12:00 event_3
#> 10 id001 2021-01-01 08:13:00 event_3
#> 11 id001 2021-01-01 08:14:00 event_3
#> 12 id001 2021-01-01 08:15:00 event_3
#> 13 id001 2021-01-01 08:16:00 event_3
#> 14 id001 2021-01-01 08:17:00 event_3
#> 15 id001 2021-01-01 08:18:00 event_3
```

> Note that from row `4` to `5` there was an interval of *2 minutes* – causing the next event to start. Same thing from row `8` to `9`: there was an interval of *4 minutes* and then the next event started.

> **PS: I need it to work fully in `dbplyr`, that is: without using `collect()`**

Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working without `collect` means we are limited to mostly dplyr functions as these are the functions for which SQL translations are defined.

Very similar to  @Sinh_Nguyen, I would propose the following:

```r
output = mf %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(time_stamp) %>%
  mutate(prev_time_stamp = lag(time_stamp, 1)) %>%
  mutate(hours_diff = DATEPART('hour', time_stamp - prev_time_stamp),
         min_part_diff = DATEPART('minute', time_stamp - prev_time_stamp)) %>%
  mutate(gap = hours_diff * 60 + min_part_diff) %>%
  mutate(is_gap = ifelse(is.na(prev_time_stamp) | gap == 1, 0, 1)) %>%
  mutate(event_index = cumsum(is_gap))
```

Notes:

- The `group_by` and `arrange` happen once at the start, but are used implicitly by the `lag` and `cumsum` functions.
- If dbplyr does not have a translation defined then it passes the command as-is. Writing `DATEPART` in capitals ensures it is not translated, so we get the PostgreSQL `DATEPART` function. I usually use SQL server, so I am following [these examples](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff) for how to calculate the difference in PostgreSQL.
- The idea of the last two lines is to create a binary indicator when a record is not a continuation of the previous event. Summing these indicators increments the event counter for each new event.
- If there are errors, you can use `show_query(output)` to view the SQL translation. Viewing / sharing the SQL translation often helps for trouble shooting.

Comment: fantastic answer!!! I only had to modify the `DATEPART` part, which I used the `hour()` and `minute()` functions from `lubridate` instead

Answer (score 1):

Here is code using the logic `1 mins` difference mean 1 event.

```
mf %>% 
  collect() %>% 
  mutate(time_stamp = as_datetime(time_stamp)) %>%
  mutate(diff_mins = difftime(time_stamp, lag(time_stamp, 1), units = "mins")) %>%
  mutate(event_count = if_else(diff_mins == 1 | is.na(diff_mins), 0, 1)) %>%
  mutate(event_index = paste0("event_", cumsum(event_count) + 1))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 5
   id    time_stamp          diff_mins event_count event_index
   <chr> <dttm>              <drtn>          <dbl> <chr>      
 1 id001 2021-01-01 08:00:00 NA mins             0 event_1    
 2 id001 2021-01-01 08:01:00  1 mins             0 event_1    
 3 id001 2021-01-01 08:02:00  1 mins             0 event_1    
 4 id001 2021-01-01 08:03:00  1 mins             0 event_1    
 5 id001 2021-01-01 08:05:00  2 mins             1 event_2    
 6 id001 2021-01-01 08:06:00  1 mins             0 event_2    
 7 id001 2021-01-01 08:07:00  1 mins             0 event_2    
 8 id001 2021-01-01 08:08:00  1 mins             0 event_2    
 9 id001 2021-01-01 08:12:00  4 mins             1 event_3    
10 id001 2021-01-01 08:13:00  1 mins             0 event_3    
11 id001 2021-01-01 08:14:00  1 mins             0 event_3    
12 id001 2021-01-01 08:15:00  1 mins             0 event_3    
13 id001 2021-01-01 08:16:00  1 mins             0 event_3    
14 id001 2021-01-01 08:17:00  1 mins             0 event_3    
15 id001 2021-01-01 08:18:00  1 mins             0 event_3
```

Comment: thank you for the nice answer – however, I need it to work with `dbplyr`, meaning without using `collect()`

Comment: What do you mean by work with `dbplyr` - you mean not using `dplyr` or what?